# Incorrect syntax near 'text'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried a lot but can't find what is wrong with this query, It gave me this error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'text'.

```
 DECLARE @ProjectSql VARCHAR(MAX)= '',  
 @UserSql VARCHAR(MAX)= '',  
 @Query VARCHAR(MAX) = ''  

 DECLARE @UserListTable TABLE  
 (  
  usedID int,  
  roleID int  
 )  


SET @UserSql = @UserSql + 
'Select DISTINCT userid,RoleID from  
(SELECT USDTL.userid,UR.RoleID ,USDTL.FirstName,USDTL.LastName,USDTL.Email,USDTL.CompanyName, 
STUFF(  
            (  
                SELECT N'', '' + R.RoleName  
                FROM                    USRMGMTUserRoles    UR  
                    INNER JOIN          USRMGMTRoles        R   ON UR.RoleId = R.RoleId  
                WHERE       UR.UserId = USDTL.UserId  
                ORDER BY    R.RoleName  
                FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE  
            ).value(''text()[1]'',''NVARCHAR(MAX)''),1,2,N''''  
        ) as ComboUserRoles  FROM USRMGMTUserDetails USDTL '  


 INSERT INTO @UserListTable  
 EXEC(@UserSql)
```

I have updated the code.

Comment: Why do you double the quote(`'`)?

Comment: Updated the code. As it was a portion of the code. Sorry for that.

Comment: The best way to debug dynamic sql is to dump the value of the sql string before attempting to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

please try the following:

```
DECLARE @ProjectSql VARCHAR(MAX)= '',  
 @UserSql VARCHAR(MAX)= '',  
 @Query VARCHAR(MAX) = ''  

 DECLARE @UserListTable TABLE  
 (  
  usedID int,  
  roleID int  
 )  


SET @UserSql = @UserSql + 
'Select DISTINCT userid,RoleID from  
(
    SELECT USDTL.userid,UR.RoleID ,USDTL.FirstName,USDTL.LastName,USDTL.Email,USDTL.CompanyName, 
    STUFF(  
                (  
                    SELECT N'', '' + R.RoleName  
                    FROM                    USRMGMTUserRoles    UR  
                        INNER JOIN          USRMGMTRoles        R   ON UR.RoleId = R.RoleId  
                    WHERE       UR.UserId = USDTL.UserId  
                    ORDER BY    R.RoleName  
                    FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE  
                ).value(''text()[1]'',''NVARCHAR(MAX)''),1,2,N''''  
            ) as ComboUserRoles  
    FROM USRMGMTUserDetails USDTL
)t'  

print @UserSql

 INSERT INTO @UserListTable  EXEC @UserSql
```

Comment: Hey, I have updated the code. The double-quote was there because it was concatenated. Sorry for the extra trouble.

Comment: I ran your code. I was getting Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near ')'.                  Line 16 is the last line with closing bracket.

Comment: @KishanKumarGupta I have updated the answer based on your new code in the question. Please try that.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
 DECLARE @ProjectSql VARCHAR(MAX)= '',  
 @UserSql VARCHAR(MAX)= '',  
 @Query VARCHAR(MAX) = ''  

 DECLARE @UserListTable TABLE  
 (  
  usedID int,  
  roleID int  
 )  


SET @UserSql = @UserSql + 
'Select DISTINCT UL.userid,UL.RoleID from  
(SELECT USDTL.userid,UR.RoleID ,USDTL.FirstName,USDTL.LastName,USDTL.Email,USDTL.CompanyName, 
STUFF(  
            (  
                SELECT N'', '' + R.RoleName  
                FROM                    USRMGMTUserRoles    UR  
                    INNER JOIN          USRMGMTRoles        R   ON UR.RoleId = R.RoleId  
                WHERE       UR.UserId = USDTL.UserId  
                ORDER BY    R.RoleName  
                FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE  
            ).value(''text()[1]'',''NVARCHAR(MAX)''),1,2,N''''  
        ) as ComboUserRoles  FROM USRMGMTUserDetails USDTL) AS UL'  


 INSERT INTO @UserListTable  
 EXEC(@UserSql)
```

You forgot to give an alias  to the 2nd `SELECT` from which you query the `userId` and the `RoleID`.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your reply. I am getting "The multi-part identifier "UR.RoleID" could not be bound." error while running. I can't figure out why?